# Laravel 4.2 Route HTTPS not working on server

Tags: laravel, https, routes, http-status-code-404

I am using laravel 4.2 and I have decided to add the http or https key in my route creation as shown in the documentation here:
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#basic-routing

In the documentation the example shows:

```
Route::get('foo', array('https', function()
{
    return 'Must be over HTTPS';
}));
```

I adjusted it in my code because I am using a controller method to route to:

```
Route::get ('/account', array('https', 'as' => 'account-get', 'uses' => 'AccountController@getIndex'));
```

Now here is where it gets strange.  On my dev server, this works just fine.  The route produces the correct url and the page loads.

But, on my production server, the route produces the correct url, but when I click on it I get a 404 error.

The other interesting thing is that if I remove the 'https' from the route, it loads just fine on http AND it loads just fine when I manually type in https for the url.  But as soon as I add it to the route definition on my production server, the 404 shows up for that page.

I thought maybe my rewrite was bad but it is the exact same as my dev environment which works as expected...just not on my prod server.

Comment: did you try clearing the cache on the server?

Comment: Looks like it was a problem with cloud flare, i will add the resolution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem solved!**

After poking around and researching for a few hours I finally realized that cloudflare was causing the issue.  To fix it, within cloudflare, I changed the Crypto->SSL (with SPDY) setting to "Full".  This took a few minutes to kick in but it all works as expected now.